# AngularJS - Form good practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

So I am new to AngularJS and I am looking to create good code because my application is going to scale.

Now, I have a list of competences that I'll get from my API, and then I need to make a list of them with a checkbox, so the user will select/deselect from the list, and then submit that form.

So how can I achieve that? What should be in the ng-model of every checkbox? Should I create a form with all the values in set in false?

Here's my controller code now:

```
function Controller(Competence) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.competences = [];

    function initController() {
        Competence.getAll()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.competences = data;
        });
    }

    initController();

}
```

And here's my view code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="90%">Competence</th>
            <th width="10%">Select</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="competence in vm.competences">
            <td>{{ competence.name }}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your code looks good. To set checkbox values, just add `ng-model="competence.selected"` to each checkbox input element like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="competence.selected">
```

Now when you select the checkbox it will set `competence.selected` to `true`, and when you deselect it the value will be `false`.

**Form Submission**

Wrap your table in a `<form>` with an `ng-submit` attribute, and create a function to submit the form:

```html
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()">

  <!-- your table here ... -->

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your controller:

```js
vm.submitForm = function(){

    vm.competences.forEach(function(competence){

        if(competence.selected) console.log(competence);

        // or POST the competences using the $http service ...

    })

  }
```

See JSFiddle also: [Checkbox Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stephentillman/txtcwer4/)

Comment: Sounds really good. Didn't realize that I could add the "selected" property to the javascript object at the view. Thought that I needed to add in the controller and then yes it would be accesible by the view. Thanks a lot!